# Event on list: find item clicked access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a list and I trigger a function on list element click.
Is there a solution to know which element has been clicked in my vba sub ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<listname>.Listindex` if you have a single-select list : [Listindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa196331%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

If you have a multi-select list, use `<listname>.ItemSelected` and iterate over the set : [ItemSelected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa196172%28v=office.11%29.aspx)